# Can I/How do I force micro-SD card to r/w mount?

Tags: linux, sd-card

I have a sandisk 64GB microSD card that I've been using in my phone. It recently started refusing to let me save things to it on the phone and I am currently trying to figure out if it's possible to fix the problem.

I have an SD card slot on my Kubuntu laptop and SD card adapter that I'm using to plug in and attempt to mount the microSD with. The problem is persisting though.
I can mount the card as read-only without a problem and have access to everything on it (which I've now copied off) and everything seems to be intact. 
I get problems as soon as I try to mount with write access. Using the following command
sudo mount -o rw,umask=000 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/exfat/
I get this output:
'WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
ERROR: fsync failed.'
and it doesn't mount.

If I use sudo mount -o ro,umask=000 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/exfat/
I still get this error 'WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.'
but it mounts and I have full access.

Does anyone know if this is salvageable or should I just give up now and get a new one?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I think this question should be posted on either http://unix.stackexchange.com, http://superuser.com or http://askubuntu.com, whichever you like most. I certainly does not belong here.

Comment: Have you run `fsck.vfat` on it to attempt to clean up any corruption? And to verify the structure of the file system and mark it as "clean"?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation but after trying all sorts of things over many minutes of frustration, I discovered there is a tiny 'read-only' switch on the side of the SD card adaptor.  Doh.